# F3 doesn't work in Eclipse for Scala-Java mixed JARs

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am unable to use F3 and other Eclipse controls when I am working with Scala code in Eclipse.

To reproduce this issue:

1. Create a new Maven project with the Spark job archetype (from here: https://github.com/jjmeyer0/spark-java-archetype)
2. Import the project into Eclipse (as existing Maven project), and add the following dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.0</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
       <version>2.11.11</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
       <version>2.11.11</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
       <version>2.11.11</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Now, from the generated code in `App.java`, if I try to do an F3 on `sc.parallelize` the `JavaSparkContext.class` file opens up, but not on the function `parallelize`. Also, F3 doesn't seem to work within the class.

I tried looking at the code on Spark Github, and I realized that F3 seems to work well within for `.class` files whose sources are in `src/main/java` https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/api/java but not in `src/main/scala` https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java

So, my question is, how do I set up Eclipse to correctly use F3 with Spark JARs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me on Eclipse Photon after some trial and error.

1. I added the Scala nature to the parent project by right clicking on the project, navigating to "Configure" and selecting "Add Scala Nature" to the project.
2. After this, I selected "Maven Dependencies" from the Package Explorer, right clicked, "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path" and edited the "Access Rules".
3. I added an access rule to make all files ("*") "Accessible".

With Photon, the above works. However, some functionalities (like F3 on function/method calls) still don't work, but at least F3 works within the Scala Spark source.

Hope this helps others, too.

Comment: The remaining part of the problem (F3 on function/method calls) was fixed by downgrading back to Eclipse Oxygen and repeating the above steps. I suppose that that was an issue caused by Photon.